# Is there an efficient way to check if there exists a linear map with the following property?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose I have two sets of non-zero vectors: $S_1 =\{v_1, \dots v_n\}$ and $S_2 = \{w_1, \dots w_n \}$ lying in $\mathbb{R}^m$ where $m < n$. Further suppose that any $m$ of the vectors from $S_1$ or from $S_2$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$. I want to know if there's an elegant way of knowing whether there exists an invertible linear map $T$ such that  $T(S_1) = T(S_2)$.

A naive way which I could theoretically write a program for is as follows: Fix any choice of $m$ vectors in $S_1$ which I please. Then any choice of $m$ vectors in $S_2$ induces a linear map $T$. I can represent this map as a matrix and check if $T(S_1) = S_2$ or not.

This requires the construction of $\binom{n}{m}m!$ linear maps, which I would likely represent as matrices in a program. Thus $\binom{n}{m}m!$ matrices of dimension $m \times m$. That's quite the calculation if $n$ is large. Is there a faster way to do this? Given the simplicity of the problem, it seems like there should be well-known faster way to do this if it exists.

Comment: Arent the maps even more - $\binom n m \times m!=\frac {n!} {(n-m)!}$, because a choice of the target $m$ vectors in $S_2$ gets you a different map for each permutation thereof? (I mean, $(v_1,v_2) \mapsto (w_1,w_2)$ is different than $(v_1,v_2) \mapsto (w_\boldsymbol 2,w_\boldsymbol 1)$)

Comment: Food for thought: for similar variations of the target $m$ vectors from $S_2$, e.g. for choices differing at a single position only, the resulting $Tv_j,j=m+1,\ldots, n$ vectors do not need full recomputation because most of the sums-of-products are the same. You can build some cache based on this and optimize the $T(S_1)=S_2$ checks by a significant factor (feels cubic to me, didn't check thoroughly though).

Comment: @Al.G. I am only looking to check whether or not $T(S_1) = S_2$. So I only need to check $\binom{n}{m} $ linear maps.

Comment: @Dan1618: I think Al.G. is right. You don't care about the order in $T(S_1)$, but still you have to choose some particular assignment of $m$ vectors in $S_1$ to $m$ vectors in $S_2$ to define a linear map. Assigning them to the same $m$ vectors in a different order yields a different linear map, and all $m!$ of those maps are potential candidates for the linear map you're looking for. (Note that this doesn't affect my answer because the absolute value of the determinant of a subset doesn't depend on the order of the vectors.)

Comment: Yes, of course. I mistakenly thought that the property of $T(S_1) = S_2$ was invariant under any permutation of the "target" vectors I use to define $T$. Though surprisingly, a lot of the set of vectors I'm working with seem to satisfy this property (but they are low dimensional).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convex hull and its topology are invariant under linear transformations. Compute the convex hull of both sets. If your matrix approach is tractable either for matching the hull points or for matching the non-hull points, you’re done. If not, find the [graphs of the hulls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#The_face_lattice) and use the information in them to limit the matches you try (e.g. matching vertices must have the same degree), or if it’s computationally feasible, you can find all isomorphisms between the graphs and only perform the matrix match for those.

Or: Compute the volumes of the convex hulls. Their quotient is the absolute value of the determinant of the putative linear map. The absolute values of the determinants of corresponding subsets of $m$ vectors would have that same ratio. Now you only have to compute the determinants of $O\left(\sqrt{\binom nm}\right)$ subsets of $m$ vectors of both sets to find a match between their determinants, and do the matrix match only when the determinants match. The downside here is that while you’ll quickly find a match if there is one, if there isn’t you only get a strong probabilistic result that there isn’t one but you can only be $100\%$ sure once you’ve tried $O\left(\binom nm\right)$ subsets.

Comment: Thank you. This is very interesting!